# How to make a field only accessible from get and set method in django Model

Tags: django, django-models

I am writing a small messaging app in django-framework.I want that my 'seen_time' and 'seen' field can only be set by my written method. Can i do that ?    Please specify

## Here is my code of 'Messages' Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.

class Messages(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(blank = False)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name = 'sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name = 'receiver')
    seen = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    sent_time = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now) 
    seen_time = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    hide = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def set_seen_true(self):
        self.seen = True
        self.seen_time = datetime.now
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common case is to have a view update the model when a particular request will be made. So at the time of the request (it could be an ajax request of course as well), you can update it however you like. So to sum up:

- Add a url in your `urls.py`
- Add a view in your `views.py` that will handle the particular request and update the model.

Another possibility is to have your model update certain fields automatically when saving the model. This could be done with [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/) such as `pre_save`. But you would *still* need to save your model in a view.

Comment: i am totally new at django and web technologies. i just don't want that i could acess my 'seen' or 'seen_time' field and set their values  from my views ......for example    i should not do this ----  msg.seen = true  ----- in my views.py file

Comment: Updated answer. You have to be clearer on what exactly you are trying to achieve and why in order to get a good answer.

Comment: Would you care to share your findings, they might be helpful for others in the future.